# How to replace only the first or second occurance of a string in a document line?

Tags: python

I have a document that has a certain string listed in it twice.
I only want to change the first line or only change the second line.  How do I specify that?

I have looked at example and I see people doing something like this:

```
line.replace('8055', '8006')
```

Changed to:

```
line.replace('8055', '8006', 1) # 1 means only change the first occurence of this string 8005 in a line
```

Here is my code:

```
    try:
        source = '//' + servername + r'/c$/my dir/mydocument.config'
        with open(source,'r') as f: # you must first read file and save lines
            newlines = []
            for line in f.readlines():
                newlines.append(line.replace('8055', '8006', 1))  # 1 means only change the first occurence of this string 8005 in a line
        with open(source, 'w') as f: # then you can open and write
            for line in newlines:
                f.seek(
                f.write(line)
        f.close()
    except:
        pass
```

Why is this not working?
This changes both lines instead of just 1.

**UPDATE**

```
    try:
        line_changed = False
        source = '//' + servername + r'/c$/my dir/myfile.config'
        with open(source,'r') as f: # you must first read file and save lines
            newlines = []
            for line in f.readlines():
                if not line_changed:
                    old_line = line
                    line = line.replace('8055', '8006', 1)  # 1 means only change the first occurence of this string 8005 in a line
                    if not old_line == line:
                        line_changed = True
                newlines.append(line)
        with open(source, 'w') as f: # then you can open and write
            for line in newlines:
                f.write(line)
        f.close()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: What error do you get?  In what way is it not working?

Comment: It makes 1 replacement per line.  So each time `line.replace()` is called on a new line, it will do the replacement once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line_changed = False
with open(source,'r') as f: # you must first read file and save lines
    newlines = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        if not line_changed:
            old_line = line
            line = line.replace('8055', '8006', 1)
            if not old_line == line:
                line_changed = True
        newlines.append(line)
```

This will make the program stop looking for additional lines to change after the first occurrence is changed.

Comment: This is removing all lines after the first line I change.

Comment: @Prox I updated the code so now it will continue reading after changing a line.

Comment: I added what I am trying at the top.  Does the code under the UPDATE section look correct?  It's not changing anything for me.

Comment: Thank you!  I was doing  something wrong.  It works now.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working :)

Let's say you have this file:

myfile.txt

```
8055 hello 8055 8055
8055
hello 8055 world 8055
hi there
```

After running the program, it has the following contents:

```
8006 hello 8055 8055
8006
hello 8006 world 8055
hi there
```

That is, your code is only replacing 1 of the items *on each line*. That is what is happening in `line.replace(...)`.

If you only want it to replace one in the *entire document* then you would want to call the `replace()` method against a string with the entire file's contents!

There are other ways to do this - for example, you could call `replace()` for each line, and once one line has a replacement then stop calling that method when you iterate through the rest of the file. Up to you to decide what makes sense.